# How to transfer a file from HostOS to GuestOS on VirtualBox?

Tags: ios, xcode, virtualbox

**HostOS : Windows 10**

**GuestOS : macOS Sierra 10.12**

Hello guys, I've been trying to install XCode on my macOS VM, it takes forever to download through the App Store, so I installed the DMG file through a torrent on my HostOS [should have downloaded it in the GuestOS =.=] I have the DMG File on my HostOS right now, how do I transfer it to the GuestOS?

- I tried putting it in a pen drive/hard disk, doesn't appear in the GuestOS.
- I tried Drag and Dropping, it doesn't work.
- I tried using the VM GuestAddition.iso sharing method, but I cannot install the PKG file, gives an error :

  > *"The operation couldn't be completed. (com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error-1.) Couldn't open VBoxSolarisAdditions.pkg"*

Could anyone help me transfer this file from my HostOS to my GuestOS with proper steps?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

I used PowerISO to save the DMG file as an ISO file, I went to the settings on the virtual box and mounted the ISO file as SATA Port 2, when I booted the Mac OS, boom, XCode DMG File was there.